# What kind of signal Voyager 1 is sending to us?

Tags: communication, voyager, radio-communication

I was reading on wiki about Voyager 1 mission and I found very interesting! One thing I did not manage to find: what is the signal Voyager 1 is sending to us? Is it simply a sinewave or something more complicated?

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: A pure sinewave carries no other information than its frequency. To transmit data you need a modulated sinewave. See wikipedia for [modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation).

Comment: Here is what I found at a Nasa site about the telemetry   "Uplink communications is via S-band (16-bits/sec command rate) while an X-band transmitter provides downlink telemetry at 160 bits/sec normally and 1.4 kbps for playback of high-rate plasma wave data. All data are transmitted from and received at the spacecraft via the 3.7 meter high-gain antenna (HGA)."

Answer (score 2):

[Voyager uses](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/DPSummary/Descanso4--Voyager_new.pdf) a type of modulation known as biphase modulation. It's rather complex to explain, but basically the phase of the signal can change rapidly. You can see a picture from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BPSK_timing_diagram.png) that shows this.

[image]